# Counterexample to show that the class of Moscow spaces is not closed hereditary.

Tags: general-topology

What is a counterexample to show that the class of Moscow spaces is not closed hereditary?

(A space $X$ is called *Moscow* if the closure of every open $U \subseteq X$ is the union of a family of G$‎_{‎\delta‎‎‎}$‎-subsets of $X$.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is <strike>essentially</strike> copied from A. V. Arhangel'skii, [*Moscow spaces and topological groups*](http://topology.auburn.edu/tp/reprints/v25/tp25222.pdf), Top. Proc., 25; pp.383-416:

> Let $D ( \tau )$ be an uncountable discrete space, and $\alpha D ( \tau )$ the one point compactification of $D ( \tau )$.  Then $D ( \tau )$ is a Moscow space, and $D ( \tau )$ is G$_\delta$-dense in $\alpha D ( \tau )$, while $\alpha D ( \tau )$ is not a Moscow space.
>   Indeed, let $U$ be any infinite countable subset of $D ( \tau )$.
>   Then $U$ is open in $\alpha D ( \tau )$, and $\overline{U} = U \cup \{ \alpha \}$, where $\alpha$ is the only non-isolated point in $\alpha D ( \tau )$.
>   Every G$_\delta$-subset of $\alpha D ( \tau )$ containing the point $\alpha$ is easily seen to be uncountable; therefore, $\overline{U}$ is not the union of any family of G$_\delta$-subsets of $\alpha D ( \tau )$.
>   Since $\alpha D ( \tau )$ is a closed subspace of a Tychonoff cube, we conclude that the class of Moscow spaces is not closed hereditary.

Comment: $1.$ Why $\alpha D ( \tau )$ is a closed subspace of tychonoff cube?   $2.$Tychonoff cube is a moscow space?

Comment: @MohammaDSina:  The Tychonoff cube $[0,1]^\kappa$ is universal for Tychonoff spaces of weight $\kappa$, and so $\alpha D ( \tau )$ is embeddable in an appropriate $[0,1]^\kappa$.  Since $\alpha D ( \tau )$ is compact, the image must be closed.

Comment: @MohammaDSina:  (Sorry, missed your second question.)  If you look at the paper I referenced/linked to, you will notice that arbitrary products of metric spaces are Moscow (this is Corollary 1.2 on p.386).

Comment: Thank you and Best wishes;)